# How can my main view controller know when the web service call finished

Tags: iphone, ios, web-services, ipad, delegates

Hi I have an web service based app that will interchange data with our server. Since I have a dedicated class doing my work, the main view controller will actually call the worker every time. The worker itself knows when the connection finished since it is a NSURLConnectionDelegate. However I need to inform the main view controller whenever the work is done. The worker is a delegate of main view controller so it knows when it need to start working. Please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should do the other way around.

First declare your worker object as a member of your main view controller(and of course, make it a property), then from you main view controller, you can just call `[self.worker sendRequstToServer]` to send the request.

Second, within your main view controller, wherever you initialize your work object, don't forget to put `self = worker.delegate`.

Third, declare a delegate method in your worker class, something like `-(void)webServiceCallFinished()`, and call `[self.delegate webServiceCallFinished]` in your worker's `-connectionDidFinishLoading()` (you might wanna do in `-parserDidEndDocument()` if you are using NSXMLParer to parse xml)

Last, you wanna declare your main view controller as the delegate of your worker class and implement `-webServiceCallFinished()`.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it in two ways:

***Approach #1:***

User Local notifications.
In the mainclass add an observer into LocalNotification Center in following way.

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(jobDone) name:@"WORKERJOBOVER" object:nil];
```

And in the worker class when the job is done, post nofitication to fire the selector:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"WORKERJOBOVER" object:nil];
```

***Approach #2:***

You can create a protocol of your worker class and add a method in the protocol which you can call on the delegate when your job is done in worker.

**WorkerClass.h**

```
//WorkerClass.h

@protocol WorkerDelegate

@interface WorkerClass: NSObject

@property (nonatomic, assign) id<WorkerDelegate> delegate

- (void)JobInProcess;
@end


@protocol WorkerDelegate
- (void)MyJobIsDone;
@end
```

**WorkerClass.m**

```
//WorkerClass.m

@implementation WorkerClass
@synthesize delegate = _delegate;

- (void)JobInProcess
{
    //When job over this will fire callback method in main class
    [self.delegate MyJobIsDone];
}
```

**MainClass.h**

```
    //MainClass.h
#import WorkerClass.h

@interface MainClass: NSObject <WorkerDelegate>


@end
```

**MainClass.m**

```
//MainClass.m

@implementation MainClass

- (void)MyJobIsDone
{
    //Do whatever you like
}
@end
```

Comment: shouldn't your delegate property be of type id<WorkerDelegate>?

Answer (score 1):

In `viewDidLoad:` of your main view controller, set it as a notification observer with `[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]`:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(webServiceContacted:) name:@"webServiceConnectionSuccessful" object:nil];
```

Then when your data was successfully interchanged with the server, post a notification within the network completion block:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"webServiceConnectionSuccessful" object:nil];
```

And `webServiceContacted:` could look like this:

```
-(void)webServiceContacted:(NSNotification *)note
{
    //do stuff here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would fire a notification from the background worker that you can listen for from your main view controller

In your View add the following when you want to listen.

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(operationComplete:) name:@"operationComplete" object:nil];
```

In your background View notify that the event completed.

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"operationComplete" object:nil];
```

Finally don't forget to remove the observer 
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];